# passing a JS variable into a vue instance

Tags: javascript, forms, laravel, vue.js, var

I got stuck on this one. I'm working on Laravel 5.5 with Vue.js.
I'm trying to pass a JS variable to my Vue Instance that takes place in my app.js file, so that my input field (created with a vue component) displays values from a previous request in case the validation fails (so that the user doesn't have to type in the content again). The reason I'm doing this is that the vue input field doesn't behave like a html input field and I have to find a workaround.

So this is my input field in my view file:

```
<input-tag id="input-tag" class="form-control" style="font-size: 22pt; resize: vertical; height: 150px; line-height: 14px" :tags.sync="inputtag" v-model="inputtag"></input-tag>
<input type="hidden" :value="inputtag" name="equipment"></input>
```

This is my JavaScript (jQuery) also in the view file:

```
var eqJSprep = '{{ $oldEquipment }}'
var eqJScommas = eqJSprep.replace(',', '"') + '"'
var eqJSready = eqJScommas.replace(new RegExp(',', 'g'), '","')

if (eqJSprep == '') {
  equipmentJS = ''
} else {
  equipmentJS = eqJSready
}
```

And this is my app.js :

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

Vue.component('input-tag', require('./components/VueTagInput.vue'));


console.log(equipmentJS)

var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#input-tag',
    data: {
      inputtag: [equipmentJS]
    }
});
```

So now, the console.log(equipmentJS) works - it shows exactly what I pass into in it my JS console in Chrome (which is the old request data).
Also, if I type in an array manually into the `inputtag:` field (app.js) the textbox shows what it should.
What I need is a dynamically created array "...", "...", "..." in here `inputtag: [HERE]`
Seems like I just can't pass my variable inside the Vue instance.

Please help if anybody has a clue.
Cheers

Comment: Is your javascript being inserted before vue.js? Probably vue.js is being loaded before your js run.

Comment: The JS is inserted in the content file, which has been yielded in a layouts file, and after the @yield in the layouts file there was the vue reference.

Comment: as I said the variable works for the console.log part, but doesn't work for data:

Comment: what happens if, in `data:`, you leave `inputtag: null`, but then below the whole `var vue = new Vue` declaration you have an additional line declaring
`vue.inputtag = [equipmentJS]`
? like in https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties this example

Comment: when I put null into inputtag: I couldn't type anything in the textfield anymore. nevermind, I used another plugin for the tag input already. thanks a lot guys!